# TDE feature in Postgresql Community edition

Tags: postgresql, tde

May I know if transparent data encryption is now available natively in PostgreSQL

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/postgresql-transparent-data-encryption/

Answer (score 1):

No, according to this page https://www.postgresql.org/about/press/faq/ it will be available in the next release (16) by September 2023.
[image]